# Need a script to calculate batch file execution time

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, time, timestamp

I need a script that I can call/include from another batch file (.bat) that can calculate the amount of time it takes to execute the first batch file.   The script would be used for automation on both Windows 7 x64 and Windows Server 2008 R2 (just incase it matters).    Any advice on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: See [How long a Batch file takes to execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739606/how-long-a-batch-file-takes-to-execute), [Calculate Time difference in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922498/calculate-time-difference-in-batch-file) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your batch call with re-directed outputs.  Then note the time the re-directed output files were created.

Example

```
echo T > start.time
do_your_batch_file
echo T > end.time
dir *.time
```